# How to extract each column data?

Tags: java, functional-programming, hashmap, java-stream, apache-commons

**Question 1:** *How to extract each column of data using the java functional programming?*

**Question 2 :** *How to extract each column of data and then put them into **Map<Date, List<Integer>>***?

[**Output of the data**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTUMN.png)

The output shown in the screenshot above is print from **`List<List<String>> covidListWithoutCountryDetails`**

**My try (but failed):**

```
Map<String, List<String>> dateWithEachDayAmountCases= new HashMap<>();
        covidListWithoutCountryDetails
                .stream()
                .map(x-> dateWithEachDayAmountCases.put(covidListWithoutCountryDetails.get(0).get(0),zeroIndexList))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                        .forEach(x->System.out.println(x));
```

**Desired output:**

```
{2020/1/22=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
{2020/1/23=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
{2020/1/24=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
...............
...............
...............
more and more until the end
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show what the data looks like before processing.

Comment: @WJS u mean the csv file? cz the output data is read from the csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first row contains date headers, and the rest rows contain values, it may be worth to prepare a list of keys for the first "row", then a map containing empty array lists per key, and then populate the column data for each date.
*Note: using `LocalDate` instead of obsolete `Date` class*

```java
List<List<String>> data = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList("2020/12/31", "2021/01/01", "2021/02/01", "2021/03/01"),
    Arrays.asList("1",   "2",  "3",  "4"),
    Arrays.asList("10", "20", "30", "40"),
    Arrays.asList("20", "40", "60", "80")
);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");

List<LocalDate> keys = data.get(0).stream().map(s -> LocalDate.parse(s, formatter)).collect(Collectors.toList());

Map<LocalDate, List<Integer>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

IntStream.range(0, data.get(0).size())
    .forEach(i -> map.put(keys.get(i), new ArrayList<>()));

data.stream()
    .skip(1)
    .forEach(row -> IntStream.range(0, row.size()) // iterate "columns" by index
        .forEach(i -> map.get(keys.get(i))
                    .add(Integer.parseInt(row.get(i)))
        )
    );
    
System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
{2020-12-31=[1, 10, 20], 2021-01-01=[2, 20, 40], 2021-02-01=[3, 30, 60], 2021-03-01=[4, 40, 80]}
```

However, Stream API does not look to be very appropriate for this task, and good old `for` loops could be used instead.

Comment: Thank you, bro. It's work. I know stream API is not very appropriate for this task, but this is one of my coursework question, and its requirement forced us to code in functional style.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you say your data is in a `List<List<String>>`.  Then try this.

- stream the lists.
- use the first element of each list as the key
- use the `subList` from 1 to end of list as the value.

```
List<List<String>> data = your data
        
Map<String,List<String>> map = data.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(list -> list.get(0),
                list -> new ArrayList<>(
                        list.subList(1, list.size()))));

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Arrays.stream I think not gonna applicable on my code. Cuz I used  ```List<List<String>> ``` to store the csv string

Comment: That information should have been included in your question. It can still work.  But why not just store the strings in a List<String>? Exactly how is your data stored?

Comment: I use the Apache Common Csv to read the csv file

Comment: ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 0``` I get this error

Comment: Can I know why u use the sublist?

Comment: I presumed that the first item in the list was the date.  So items 1 thru N was the data.  I used the sublist to grab that, pass it to an `ArrayList` constructor to create the value for the date key.

Comment: The dates are stored in the first row, not in the first "column".